# Bad audio output in stereo mode - FFMPEG PortAudio C++

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, portaudio

I'm here again. This time I am working with the audio, I had before some memory leaks issues but now they are solved, this time I am here with a new problem, when I configure portaudio to sound in stereo (channels = 2), the audio outputs in a bad quality.

It only outputs good in mono, there is almost no solution in google (Or I am a bad 'googler'), here is the code:

**Thread that plays audio:**

```
int16_t* audioBuffer=(int16_t*)av_malloc(FRAME_SZ_AV);


int sz = MEDIA->DecodeAudioFrame(audioBuffer,0);

if(sz==1)
    Pa_WriteStream(MEDIA->output_stream,audioBuffer,MEDIA->_audio_ccontext->frame_size);

if(sz!=1)
    MessageBox(0,"error","error",MB_OK);

ZeroMemory(audioBuffer,FRAME_SZ_AV);
av_freep(&audioBuffer);
```

**DecodeAudioFrame function**

```
int WbMedia::DecodeAudioFrame(int16_t *audio_buf, int buf_size){
int return_status=0;
AVPacket t_pack;

while(!audio_packets.empty()){
    // Get new packet
    WaitForSingleObject(Queue_Audio_Mutex,INFINITE);
    t_pack = audio_packets.front();
    audio_packets.pop();
    ReleaseMutex(Queue_Audio_Mutex);

    int obt_size = AVCODEC_MAX_AUDIO_FRAME_SIZE;
    int consm = avcodec_decode_audio3(_audio_ccontext,audio_buf,&obt_size,&t_pack);
    if(consm > 0 && obt_size > 0){
        return_status=1;
        break;
    }
    return_status=-1;
    break;
}

av_free_packet(&t_pack);

return return_status;
}
```

**PortAudio Settings**

```
output_params.device = Pa_GetDefaultOutputDevice(); //choosen_device.dev_index;
output_params.sampleFormat=paInt16;
output_params.channelCount=channel_count;
output_params.suggestedLatency=choosen_device.dev_inf->defaultLowOutputLatency;
output_params.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo=NULL;

// Start with PA opening
PaError pa_opening_err = Pa_OpenStream(&output_stream,
    NULL,
    &output_params,
    sample_fr,
    _audio_ccontext->frame_size,
    paNoFlag,
    NULL,
    NULL
);
```

Why is the audio outputting in bad quality in stereo and not in mono? How can I fix it?

Comment: You are probably mixing interleaved and non-interleaved audio.

Comment: Hmmm, how does that work? Interleaved audio and planar audio? I know what interleaved is, what is planar? So, do I need to work with interleaved for stereo?

Comment: Interleaved audio is formatted as alternating left and right samples: LRLRLRLR. Non-interleaved is formatted as a chunk of left, then a  chunk of right: LLLLLRRRRR. This may help: http://blog.bjornroche.com/2011/11/slides-from-fundamentals-of-audio.html

Answer (score 0):

not sure,

but instead of using **paInt16** you can use **paInt24** (24bit sampleformat) for better sound quality. I do agreed to bjornroche that you may Interleaved the stereo output between left and right, though please check the callback function and output data